# so far with past simple?

Tags: past-tense

I first heard from you yesterday while I was browsing the New bandcamp releases on vinyl .I   listened to your track called "Room" liked it  very much  and immediately  went to your bandcamp site to see what you **released** so far.

Can I use "so far" with past simple in this case, I think so but I am not sure, I know normally so far goes with perfect tenses but I  already saw "so far" with past simple meaning until now

Comment: A British English speaker would say _what you have released so far_.

Comment: even if the text is about yesterday

Comment: _So far_ means _up to now_. On the timescale of releasing records, I think 'yesterday' counts as 'now'. If the time in question was a long time ago, it would have to be _had released_.

Comment: you mean if the text was about 10 years ago

Comment: I think this is a case where the perfect ("have released") would be more correct, but native speakers might still use the shorter, simpler form ("released") in casual speech.

Comment: I didn't mean any specific time interval! _I asked him how many records he had released so far_.

Comment: but why does "so far " not imply up to now (today)  if it implies up to yesterday past perfect should be better, I don't understand

Comment: Because the point reference is Yesterday so what happened before should be past perfect